# page not found with two parameter htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hello I am cleaning up my urls by using the htaccess file.
I have a parameter called: page and a parameter called: id.

so my original url is:
http://bouwen040.sayhey.nl/index.php?page=leden&id=15

and I would like it to be:
http://bouwen040.sayhey.nl/leden/15

the page that calls only the 'page' parameter works. The other one is giving a page not found error.

this is my rewriterule code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2
```

I also tried this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

I just don't know why one parameter works and two doesn't ?

Comment: Note: if I leave it like http://bouwen040.sayhey.nl/index.php?page=leden&id=15 it does work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```